# Date format change in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have start date : 28 February 2018

**HTML**

```
 <div class="input-group date form_date" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy" data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="check_in" placeholder="Check In" required >    
</div>
```

**Now, I want to change this format to in JavaScript**

Feb 28 2018

Is there a way of doing it in JavaScript?

Comment: And your try is.....can you post it?

Comment: And where is the date on the page?

Comment: you can changed the date-format in your field.

Comment: date pick by using datepicker function

Comment: i want date in that format in my field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert dates in JavaScript, you need to [use the `Date()` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). I don't know how and where exactly you want to get your input date, but the below snippet will give you an idea about how to use the `Date()` object for your purpose.

```js
var Months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
$('#date').change(function() {
    // Get the date from the input field
    var inputDate = $('#date').val();
    // Convert the date to a Date() object
    var date = new Date(inputDate);
    // Now that we have the object ready, we can use its getDate(), getMonth() and getFullYear() methods
    var outputDate = Months[date.getMonth()] + ' ' + date.getDate() + ' ' + date.getFullYear();
    // Append the result
    $('#result').text(outputDate);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="date" type="date">
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert dates in JavaScript, you need to use the Date() object.Here val is my input date : 28 February 2018

```
var date = new Date(val);
```

And the output will be

Wed Feb 28 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)